# manually backward elimination when intercept is not significant in R?

Tags: r

I am using the following code to do Backward Elimination:

```
regressor = lm (formula = y ~ a + b + c + d + e, data = dataset)
summary (regressor)
```

then remove the predictor with the highest P-value.

eg. if c has the largest p-value, then

```
regressor = lm (formula = y ~ a + b + d + e, data = dataset)
summary (regressor)
```

repeat until we have all variables with p-value < Significant Level.

But I encounter a problem here, I found the intercept has the largest p-value and I cannot specify or remove it in "regressor".

Could someone help me out here plz?

Comment: Answer: Don't remove the intercept.  There are some cases where it makes sense but if you don't fully understand the implications then I don't think you'd be making a good call when removing the intercept.

Comment: Have you looked at the `step` function or the `stepAIC` (in MASS package).  Here is a well tested automated function for this task.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're asking is how to run a regression without an intercept? Then you can do so using Y~x1+x2...**-1** as your formula in lm().